# How to make Android custom clock time accurate?

Tags: android, timer, handler

I made a appWidget which show the current time of the server(2012-08-29, 12:00:08 for example). I request the server time every fix duration(1 hour for example). If receives the server time, updates the appWidget display. During the duration, I launch a Handler to update the time like this:

```
  mTick = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mMillis += 1000;
            long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            long next = now + (1000 - now % 1000);
            mHandler.postAtTime(mTicker, next);
        }
    }
    mTicker.run();
```

My questions:
1 After a long time(one day elapsed), The time displayed in AppWidget is slow than the real server time.
I doubt that my method used above is not accurate enough to update the time.
Any suggestions about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use [SystemClock.uptimeMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis%28%29) because it does not include time spent in deep sleep, thats why your app widget is out of sync.

You should use [SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29) call instead

Upd: sorry, I think I misunderstand the problem here. What you are trying to do is to use postAtTime to post runnable after some time in future. Please notice that postAtTime does not include time when device is in deep sleep.

What you need is to track accurate ammount of deltas between redrawing of your widget. You should use SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() for that.

Algorithm should be like this:

```
long serverTime = getServerTime();
long lastTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

// Somewhere in updateWidget() or call on timer:
serverTime = serverTime  + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastTime;
lastTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
// At this moment in serverTime variable you have "server" time adjusted by the time which passed on device, including time spent in deep sleep
```

Comment: Thank your reply.
    `// Somewhere in updateWidget() or call on timer:
    serverTime = serverTime  + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastTime;`
"SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastTime" is the time cost of my "updateWidget()" code?

Comment: another problem:
I wonder that when in deeply sleep, CPU may not execute the code above. After wake up, the time stay in when going into sleep.
If that, How can I retrieve the time elapsed during deeply sleep?
I tried to receive the "ACTION_SCREEN_ON/OFF" to record the moment of screen off/on, but it is not accurate.

Comment: Just use SysemClock.elapsedRealtime() it should be enough for you because it does not matter what happened between updates of your widgets. And if your code is not executed during deep sleep it does not matter either, because user is not interacting with the phone.

Comment: Thank your suggestion.Just as your reply, my program is OK now.